# Как создавать отдельную таблицу для пользователя?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, peewee

Пишу некий опросник, и возникла проблема с сохранением вопросов/ответов пользователей. Не могу понять, как создавать отдельно таблицу для пользователя в коде (если конечно для него ещё нет таблицы), чтобы код мог с ней работать. Буду очень благодарен за объяснение

Вот примерные поля для такой таблички:

```
class UserTable(peewee.Model):
    """База данных пользователя"""

    id = peewee.IntegerField(unique=True)
    # вопрос 1
    q1 = peewee.CharField(null=True)
    # вопрос 2
    q2 = peewee.CharField(null=True)
    # вопрос 3
    q3 = peewee.CharField(null=True)
    # вопрос 4
    q4 = peewee.CharField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        database = database
```

Comment: Сделать еще один класс от модели, в нем будут поля для пользователя. Текущий класс переименовать, т.к. это скорее `Question`, а не `User`. Сделать еще таблицу `Answer`, в ней хранить ответы на вопрос, сам вопрос и юзера

Comment: @gil9red, проблема в том, что пользователей может быть 10, 100, 1000 и т.д. Для каждого класс не напишешь(

Comment: @NikUvolen не важно, сколько пользователей )) создайте три модели (User, Answer, Question), как советовал gil9red, свяжите внешними ключами и сохраняйте/отбирайте что вам нужно

Comment: @NikUvolen, как уже написали, не нужно вам для каждого пользователя создавать класс-модель. Смотрите, каждый класс тут это отдельная таблица в базе данных. У пользователей будет своя таблица. Для связи одной таблицы к другой используйте внешние ключи это поле с типом `ForeignKeyField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет нужды делать много табличек.
В твоей табличке у пользователя есть уникальный идентификатор: `UserTable.id`.
Значит в ней можно хранить сколько угодно пользователей - каждый со своим `id`.

Возможно нужно добавить в таблицу поле `name` - чтобы хранить имя.